# How to insert a markdown table in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, markdown, jetbrains-ide

I'm using IDEA 2019.3 Ultimate edition which ships with markdown support. I'm trying to insert a table like this:

```
| Key   | Func   |
|-------|--------|
| cmd+n | search |
```

but I found `tab` not working and IDEA doesn't help to indent the table so I have to manually add lots of `-`. Is there an efficient way to insert a table in IDEA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `2022.1` you can use `Code > Generate... > Table` or `Insert... > Table` (`cmd-N`) to insert tables.

You can checkout [official IDEA documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/markdown.html#insert-table) for table support in Markdown plugin.

Comment: cmd-N works better than type the frame manually.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure there is an empty line above the table for it to be rendered:

```
Some texts:

| Tables   |      Are      |  Cool |
|----------|:-------------:|------:|
| col 1 is |  left-aligned | $1600 |
| col 2 is |    centered   |   $12 |
| col 3 is | right-aligned |    $1 |
```

(using activedecay's text example)

Answer (score 7):

Intellij community edition 2020.3.3

```
|header 1|header 2|
---|---
|xyz|x|
|xyz|y|
```

Answer (score 2):

Works for me in IntelliJ IDEA version 2020.2.3

```
| Tables   |      Are      |  Cool |
|----------|:-------------:|------:|
| col 1 is |  left-aligned | $1600 |
| col 2 is |    centered   |   $12 |
| col 3 is | right-aligned |    $1 |
```

Answer (score 2):

This does not address the OP's original problem, but hopefully it can help others that arrive here as a result of IDEA not rendering their markdown tables.

In my case I needed to add more `-` characters on the second line. IDEA seems to require a minimum of 3 dashes in order to display the markdown table.

#### Incorrect

##### Input

```markdown
| Some | Table | Header | Values | 
| :-: | :-: | :-- | --: |
| Centre | Centre | Left | Right |
```

##### Output

```
| Some | Table | Header | Values | 
| :-: | :-: | :-- | --: |
| Centre | Centre | Left | Right |
```

#### Correct

##### Input

```markdown
| Some | Table | Header | Values | 
| :---: | :---: | :--- | ---: | 
| Centre | Centre | Left | Right |
```

##### Output

```
 -----------------------------------
|  Some  |  Table | Header | Values |
| Centre | Centre | Left   |  Right |
 -----------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible at the moment.

As a workaround you can use the [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) which lets you generate the markdown code while being able to input data in a normal table.

Comment: This is a good solution for all the range of text editors. I doubt IntelliJ Idea has any solution to this (probably a plugin, however, I find this better).

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, but I was looking for a solution which supported in Idea it self.

Comment: I think that at the moment there is none. That is why I provided this workaround, as I was looking for a way some time ago myself. Maybe one can open a feature request at jetbrains. Other people would probably like to use this as well.